# Ray Tracing with GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, raytracing

i tried to implement a simple raytracing algorithm in an openGl fragment shader which draws a single sphere.

sometimes it draws a distorted sphere, but most of the times it draws nothing. 
with the actual sphere origin and radius i get a slightly destored sphere in the right upper corner.

```
#version 430 core

uniform ivec2 viewportDimensions;
uniform mat4 gl_ProjectionMatrix;
uniform ivec4 viewport;

out vec3 color;

struct Ray {
    vec3 origin;
    vec3 direction;
};

struct Sphere {
    vec3 origin;
    float radius;
};

float zNear = -0.1f;
float zFar = -100.0f;
float fieldOfViewX = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 / 2.0f;

float sampleRay(Ray ray,Sphere s, float distance);
Ray computeEyeRay(float, float, int, int);
bool intersect(Ray r, Sphere s);
bool solveQuadratic(float a, float b, float c);
Ray calcEyeFromWindow(vec3 windowSpace);

void main() {
//  Ray r = computeEyeRay(gl_FragCoord.x + 0.5f, gl_FragCoord.y + 0.5f, viewportDimensions.x, viewportDimensions.y);
    Ray r = calcEyeFromWindow(vec3(gl_FragCoord.x + 0.5f, gl_FragCoord.y + 0.5f, 1f));
    Sphere s;
    s.origin = vec3(0.5f,-0.5f,-0.7f);
    s.radius = 0.8f;

    if (intersect(r,s))
        color = vec3(1,1,1);
    else
        color = vec3(0,0,0);
    }

Ray calcEyeFromWindow(vec3 windowSpace)
{
    vec4 ndcPos;
    ndcPos.xy = ((2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy) - (2.0 * viewport.xy)) / (viewport.zw) - 1;
    ndcPos.z = (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.z - gl_DepthRange.near - gl_DepthRange.far) /
    (gl_DepthRange.far - gl_DepthRange.near);
    ndcPos.w = 1.0;

    vec4 clipPos = ndcPos / gl_FragCoord.w;
    vec4 eyePos = inverse(gl_ProjectionMatrix) * clipPos;

    Ray r;
    r.origin = eyePos.xyz;
    r.direction =normalize(eyePos.xyz);

    return r;
}

Ray computeEyeRay(float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    const float aspect = float(height) / float(width);
    const float s = -2.0f * tan(fieldOfViewX * 0.5f);

    const vec3 start = vec3( (float(x) / float(width) - 0.5) * s,
                        -(float(y) / float(height) - 0.5f) * s * aspect,
                        1.0f) * zNear;
    float startLength = sqrt( (start.x * start.x) + (start.y * start.y) + (start.z * start.z) );

    Ray e;
    e.origin = start;
    e.direction = normalize(start);
    return e;
}

bool intersect(Ray r, Sphere s) {
    float a = dot(r.direction,r.direction);
    float b = dot(r.direction, 2.0 * (r.origin-s.origin));
    float c = dot(s.origin, s.origin) + dot(r.origin,r.origin) +-2.0*dot(r.origin,s.origin) - (s.radius*s.radius);

    float disc = b*b + (-4.0)*a*c;

    if (disc < 0)
        return false;

    return true;

}


bool solveQuadratic(float a, float b, float c) {
    float t, t_1;

    float disc = a * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (disc < 0) 
        return false;
    else {
        if (disc == 0)
            t = -0.5 * b / a;
        else {
            float q = (b > 0) ? -0.5 * (b+sqrt(disc)) : -0.5 * (b-sqrt(disc));
            t = q / a;
            t_1 = c / q;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

here is the rest of the program if anyone wants to compile and test it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>

// include opengl headers
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

const int VIEWPORT_DIMENSION_X = 1280;
const int VIEWPORT_DIMENSION_Y = 1280;

void glutInitialization(int argc, char **argv);
void glewInitialization();
void display();
void resize(int w, int h);
void idle();
void drawSphere(float x, float y, float z);
GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path);

GLuint VertexArrayID;
GLuint vertexbuffer; // This will identify our vertex buffer
GLuint programID;

static const GLfloat quadvertices[] = {
    -1.0f, 1.0f, .0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, .0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, .0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, .0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, .0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, .0f
    };

static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    glutInitialization(argc, argv);
    glewInitialization();

    // create VAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Generate 1 buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

    // Give our vertices to OpenGL.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadvertices), quadvertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // 
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    programID = LoadShaders( "vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl" );

    glViewport(0,0,1280,1280);
    // create uniform variables
    GLint viewportDimensionsHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "viewportDimensions");
    glProgramUniform2i(programID, viewportDimensionsHandle, VIEWPORT_DIMENSION_X, VIEWPORT_DIMENSION_Y);

    GLint viewportHandle =glGetUniformLocation(programID, "viewport");
    glProgramUniform4i(programID, viewportHandle, 0,0,1280,1280);


    // start mainloop
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void glutInitialization(int argc, char **argv) {
    // GLUT initializing
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(1280,1280);
    glutCreateWindow("raycasting");

    // register GLUT callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
}

void glewInitialization() {
    // GLEW initializing
    glewInit();
    if (glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_4_3"))
        printf("Ready for OpenGL 4.3\n");
    else {
        printf("OpenGL 4.3 not supported\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use our shader
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // Bind VAO
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Draw the triangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle

    // Unbind VAO
    glBindVertexArray(0); 

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void resize(int w, int h) {

}

void idle() {

}

void drawSphere(float x, float y, float z) {
    glPushMatrix();
}

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path){

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Link the program
    fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage( std::max(InfoLogLength, int(1)) );
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;
}
```

Comment: Pass the viewport dimensions to the shader as a uniform, along with the inverse projection matrix, and apply the formulae [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space). This gives a view or 'eye' coordinate space ray from [0,0,0,1] through [x,y,z,w], or just [0,0,0] -> [x/w,y/w,z/w]. You can then set up a sphere somewhere inside the view volume.

Comment: i.e., use glViewport to handle the aspect ratio, rather than using trigonometric functions in the fragment shader.

Comment: i tried to implement what you suggested but something isnt quite right. now i see no sphere instead there are 2 triangles. http://s14.directupload.net/images/140712/temp/6yog4cpj.png  i updated the code i posted with the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's not a complete solution, but it finally draws a sphere:

```
 #version 430 core
    
    uniform ivec2 viewportDimensions;
    uniform mat4 gl_ProjectionMatrix;
    uniform ivec4 viewport;
    uniform float imageAspectRatio;
    uniform float angle;
    
    out vec3 color;
    
    struct Ray {
        vec3 origin;
        vec3 direction;
    };
    
    struct Sphere {
        vec3 origin;
        float radius;
    };
    
    bool intersect(Ray r, Sphere s);
    
    
    void main() {

        focal = 60;
        angle = tan(focal * 0.5 * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 / 180); // convert from degree to radian
        float xx = (2 * (gl_FragCoord.x + 0.5) / viewportDimensions.x - 1) * angle * imageAspectRatio;
        float yy = (1 - 2 * (gl_FragCoord.y + 0.5) / viewportDimensions.y) * angle;
    
        vec3 rayOrigin = vec3(0,0,0);
        vec3 rayDirection = normalize(vec3(xx, yy, -1) - rayOrigin);
    
        Ray r;
        r.origin = rayOrigin;
        r.direction = rayDirection;
        
        Sphere s;
        s.origin = vec3(0.0f,0.0f,-1.1f);
        s.radius =0.55f;
    
    
        if (intersect(r,s))
            color = vec3(1,0,1);
        else
            color = vec3(0,0,0);
        }
    
    bool intersect(Ray r, Sphere s) {
        float a = dot(r.direction,r.direction);
        float b = dot(r.direction, 2.0 * (r.origin-s.origin));
        float c = dot(s.origin, s.origin) + dot(r.origin,r.origin) +-2.0*dot(r.origin,s.origin) - (s.radius*s.radius);
    
        float disc = b*b + (-4.0)*a*c;
    
        if (disc < 0)
            return false;
    
        return true;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
e.origin = start;
e.direction = normalize(start);
```

That looks wrong.

Considering this in an Eye-Ray the origin should be the Eye-Position.

```
e.origin = vec3(0,0,0);
```

Comment: i copied the "computeEyeRay" function from the Computer Graphics (john f. hughes) book. i get the same output if i put the origin at vec3(0,0,0) instead. so i assume the function is correct.

Comment: Try passing through the vertices to the fragment shader and use: Ray r = computeEyeRay(vertex.x + 1.0f * 1280, vertex.y + 1.0f * 1280, 1280, 1280); - never trust old gl variabless like gl_fragCoords ;)

Comment: but wouldnt this destroy the whole ray tracing? now i send a ray for every pixel. if i use the vertices coordinates i only send a ray for every vertex? i tested gl_fragCoords a bit and they seem to do what they should. as example i colored every pixel with gl_fragCoord.x > 100 or similar. and the output was exactly was i expected. did this in a dozen different ways.